# Proc SQL, Aggregate of calculated value

Tags: proc-sql

My current query is as follows:

```
create table Report as
select distinct
    a.Var1,
    count(distinct b.Var2) as Var2,

from tbl1 a

inner join tbl2 b
on a.Var3=b.Var3 and a.Var4=b.Var4

inner join tbl3 c
on c.Var3=b.Var3

group by a.Var1
order by Var2 desc
;
```

This works fine and I get the following result

Var1-----------------------------------------------Var2------------------------------------------------------------------------
COCA COLA ZERO CAN 8X330ML-----19279------------------------------------------------------------------
BULK VEGETABLES------------------------11723----------------------------------------------------------------
BULK FRUITS---------------------------------10496--------------------------------------------------------------
BREAD-------------------------------------------6605------------------------------------------------------------------

My issue is that I want to add a third column that calculates the percentage of Var2/max(Var2). Keep in mind that this max is always in the first row (if that helps).

So I want my result to be

Var1----------------------------------------------Var2 ---Var3

COCA COLA ZERO CAN 8X330ML-----19279 -100%

BULK VEGETABLES------------------------11723 --60.81%

BULK FRUITS---------------------------------10496-- 54.44%

BREAD-------------------------------------------6605--- 34.26%

I tried

```
create table Report as
   select distinct
   a.Var1,
   count(distinct b.Var2) as Var2,
   calculated Var2/max(calculated Var2)
```

but I get the error "Summary functions nested in this way are not supported.
"

Answer (score 1):

You can always nested queries:

```
create table Report as  
select  
    Var1,  
    Var2,  
    Var2/max(Var2) as pct_Var2  
from (  
    select distinct  
        a.Var1,  
        count(distinct b.Var2) as Var2  
    from  
        (...)  
    group by a.Var1  
)
```