# SAS proc SQL nested function

Tags: sql, sas

guys,

my goal is simple. Counting the numbers (surgid) by groups first, then get the mean within each group. I tried two SQL, neither was succeeded. Wandering anyone know how should I nested the codes?

Thanks,
Andrea

First try:

```
proc sql;
create table bhr_surg as
select a.*, mean(b.numsurg) as meansurg from bhr as a,
(select count(b.surgid) as numsurg from bhr as b)

where surgid not in (1,2,3,7777)
group by surgid,procyr;
quit;
```

Second try:

```
proc sql;
create table bhr_surg as
select *, count(surgid) as numsurg, mean(calculated numsurg) as meansurg from bhr

where surgid not in (1,2,3,7777)
group by surgid,procyr;
quit;
```

Comment: What are the columns in bhr? When you say it doesn't work, what is the error message? Even better, provide a stand-alone example using the sashelp library as sample data, please.

Comment: In the first example"from bhr as a" isn't valid syntax. Aliases in the FROM clause use a syntax like "from bhr a" (no "as")

Comment: Hi Snorehorse, In the first example, two errors. First is "Column numsurg could not be found in the table/view identified with the correlation name B." Second is "The MEAN summary function requires a numeric argument." I think the second one is because of the first. "as" does not really matter here. I delete "as", the same error. The data is pretty simple, surgid is surgeon id. I want to count each surgeon (surgid) in different year (procyr).

Comment: @andrea please post some sample data to work with, thanks

Comment: @Andrea You want to count each distinct surgid, by procyr. And then you want the mean of those counts?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983321/proc-sql-aggregate-of-calculated-value , see the nested queries in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're grouping by something in addition to `surgid`, so your counts and means are counts and means of a subset of your id groups. The following should work:

```
data have;
  input surgid numsurg;
  datalines;
10 1000 
10 1500 
10 2000 
20 3000 
20 4000 
30 2500 
;
run;


proc sql;
    create table want as select distinct
        *, count(numsurg) as count, mean(numsurg) as mean
        from have
        group by surgid;
quit;
```